# NetBSD: /etc/man.conf man search path does not work

Tags: man, netbsd

I've added a new man page directory

```
/usr/local/share/man/man1b
```

which contains files like e.g.

```
troff.1b
```

In /etc/man.conf I added

```
_subdir ...some names... man1b
_default /usr/{share,X11R7,X11R6,pkg,local,local/share}/man/
local /usr/local/share/man/
1b {cat,man}1b
```

*man -p* prints

```
...
/usr/local/share/man/man1b
```

But if I input

```
man 1b troff
```

I get the error message

```
man: no entry for troff in the manual.
```

(I can't use *man troff* since *groff* is installed too with a man page elsewhere in cat1.)

How can I add the man path correctly?

PS: If I rename the file to *troff.1* then *man 1b troff* works. But I thought that the category can also be the file name extension. Could it be a bug of NetBSD (file name *troff.1b* works in OpenBSD and Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your MANPATH environment variable, at least that is what I did in this situation.

```
$ export MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man/
```

From the man page (for man):

> ```
>    MANPATH
>           If MANPATH is set, man uses it as the path to search
>           for manual page files.  It overrides the configuration
>           file and the automatic search path, but is overridden by
>           the -M invocation option. See SEARCH PATH FOR MANUAL PAGES.
> ```